# Magento 2.1 security: Arbitrary PHP from database fields

Tags: php, magento-2.1, security

I have a basic security question about Magento 2.1

Do any of the modules in a default installation allow the execution of arbitrary PHP code directly from a database field? I'm assuming not, but I need to check.

Comment: you can check all the files in the folders called `Setup` inside each module. I would say no, but you can check it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This would be a major security flaw that I cannot imagine would make it through code review at Magento.

To confirm, search for usages of the `eval` PHP function in the code base: no results.

Comment: Always remember: `eval === evil`. But beware of 3rd party extensions: there are some extensions out there that indeed store PHP code in the database and use `eval()` to run it. Always code review 3rd party extensions!